# How can we link together these web-api question posts about getting the dimensions of base64-encoded images?

Tags: discussion, canonical

I just encountered this question and thought—there has got to be a duplicate target for this: [How to get the dimensions of Base64 encoded image in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75240174/11107541).

I did a Google search (`get dimensions of dataurl image site:stackoverflow.com`) and found a lot of related-looking-ones with similar questions and similar answers. It seems like there's probably opportunity for linking these together for the benefit of future readers, either by non-duplicate links (for example, linking via comments), or duplicate links.

1. [JS - get image width and height from the base64 code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17774928/11107541)
2. [How to find the base64 image width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14274822/11107541)
3. [Get height and width dimensions from base64 PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15327959/11107541)
4. [Get dimensions from Base64 encoded image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44306245/11107541)
5. [How can i get the Height and Width of image having base64 string source?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50708637/11107541)
6. [how to get width height of an base 64 image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63969580/11107541)

Others that look less similar, but which still look related:

7. [How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/623172/11107541)
8. [Getting Image Dimensions using Javascript File API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7460272/11107541)

Do any of these make sense to be signposts to other ones? If so, which ones?

I have some knowledge of JavaScript and web APIs, but not enough to feel comfortable initiating anything here.

Comment: Yes, there must be a canonical duplicate somewhere for such a basic question. But the ***search engine cutoff*** has seen to questions from 2013 being the youngest in 1. - 6. That's nearly 2,000 days after Stack Overflow launched. It is hard to imagine this wasn't asked in the first hours, days, weeks or months of Stack Overflow's existence.

Answer (score 3):

Of the bunch... I think the one you found originally that triggered you to go look is actually the least bad.

I pick those words carefully because I still don't really consider the answer "good". The root issue in all of these questions is misunderstanding. Not knowing how images work in a web page, not knowing how to manipulate them in JavaScript, not understanding that images are loaded asynchronously. A lot of these questions for example ask specifically about Base64-encoded images, but that is a red herring. It is no different from an image loaded from a URL.

An answer which does not address any of that and especially does not address the asynchronous nature is essentially a code-only answer in my book. Not good, even if the code works.

Comment: I'm not sure about least bad... It's been using an image of response data from revision 1. So you can't even know that they're talking about a [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs) without the image. Though I do agree that there's some missing terminology ("misunderstanding") in these question posts- particularly that they say "base64" instead of "data URL".

Comment: @user opinions are such fickle beasts :) Regardless of which one is the least bad, they're all "not good".